# I'm using Mamp so I can use phpAdmin for my react native project. How can I fix the root folder

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, react-native

The Mamp docs say you should put your php files to connect to your mysql database in the mamp htdocs folder because that's the root folder. Is there a way to put a file in the htdocs folder so I can point to my php files in my react-native project's folder instead of having them in mamp htdocs folder.

Answer (score 0):

In MAMP you can point your document root into any folder, not only htdocs.